# Emit JS code from an HTML helper MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Say I want to write an HTML helper to draw a chart.
This helper would need to emit specific JS script code into the body of the page it was called from.

Is this recommended ?

If not how would i workaround that ?

Can i tell the helper to emit the code into a specific section defined in the main layout ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HelloWorld(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("alert('Hello World');");
    }
}
```

In Your Razor View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    @Html.HelloWorld();

</script>
```

You probably should not be doing this.

I would consider JS front end content that forms part of your view. Your view should simply display your view model.

I would be interested in knowing why you feel you need to be able to deliver JS in this way?

Comment: my need is to create a JSplot HtmlHelpr. drawing graphs with JSPlot require alot of js code to be emitted, can you think of any other way ?

Comment: sounds like a good enough reason, the above code should work then. give it a try.